# Using a color cycler more than once in a single matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following code is called twice in succession for two different sets of `evts` events data:

```
  mpl.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'] = plt.cycler('color',colors)
  for e in evts:
    ef = e[e[:,0]<3500]
    plt.plot(ef[:,0],ef[:,1]) # ,cmap='Greens')
```

The first invocation is with `mpl.cm.Greens` and the second with `mpl.cm.Reds`.   It seems though that only the *first* invocation of setting `mpl.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle']` actually "takes":  even though both `Greens` and `Reds` were provided all of the data series are instead printed in Green:

[image]

So is it possible to invoke two different cycler's for one plot?

**Update** Here is the output and code for it using the accepted answer from @ImportanceOfBeingEarnest:

```
def plotEvts(evts, colors):
  ax = plt.axes()
  ax.set_prop_cycle(plt.cycler('color',colors))
  for e in evts:
    ef = e[e[:,0]<3500]
    plt.plot(ef[:,0],ef[:,1]) # ,cmap='Greens')
  plt.title('Faster RCNN Overall Loss Progression')
  plt.xlabel('Steps Count: Approx 25 steps per minute')
  plt.ylabel('Loss')

  evt_colors = [ (mpl.cm.Greens,'/data/tfevents/sobelXYCanny'),
                (mpl.cm.Reds,'/data/tfevents/baseline')]
  for cmapMonad, ddir in evt_colors:
    evts = processFiles(ddir)
    colors = cmapMonad(np.linspace(0,1,2*len(evts))[len(evts):-1])
    plotEvts(evts,colors)
  plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name `axes.prop_cycle` suggests, the cycle is a property of the axes. That property is set at axes creation time. Subsequently, the same property cycler is used within the same axes.

You may change the property cycler via [`Axes.set_prop_cycle()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_prop_cycle.html) in between your two codes though.

Comment: nice! trying it out now

Comment: How is the method invoked? I tried `Axes.set_prop_cycle(plt.cycler('color',colors))` but that is incorrect "Expected type _AxesBase: got Cycler instead"

Comment: If `ax` is your axes, you need to use `ax.set_prop_cycle(...)`. (I'm always happy to provide runnable code if the question contains a [mcve]).

Comment: ah. i did not actually define any `axes` (single plot).  i will create axes now

Comment: Got a warning doing that ;) but it did work . Put updates in OP

Answer (score 0):

In parallel with the esteemed @ImportaneOfBeingEarnest answer I used the following workaround - that is to combine the color cycles into one big one:

```
  evt_colors = [ (mpl.cm.Greens,'/data/tfevents/sobelXYCanny'),
                (mpl.cm.Reds,'/data/tfevents/baseline')]
  evts = []
  colors = []
  for cmapMonad, ddir in evt_colors:
    evts.extend(processFiles(ddir))
    colors.extend( cmapMonad(np.linspace(0,1,2*len(evts))[len(evts):-1]))
  plotEvts(evts,colors)
  plt.show()
```

This gives the desired effect

[image]

In any case I will try out his answer as well now.